# React, Redux. Text translation

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux-i18n

I am currently working on React application and I need to implement translation inside of it. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-redux-i18n
I am using this library to achieve the translation.

I am also using functional components with compose library, so I need to use Translate component instead of i18n.t function.

However I have faced an issue, that I cannot translate placeholders inside of functional component. Translate component returns an object instead of text and i18n.t function does not rerender on component update.

Could anyone help me, please, and tell, how I can achieve translation of placeholders with this library?